# hiberfile.sys, pagefile.sys and is_file()

Tags: php, windows

I'm making a file explorer with php and I have a problem whith the function is_file()
why does this code returns false ?

```php
is_file('/hiberfile.sys')
```

it's the same result with pagefile.sys.
is there an other way to check if a file is a true file ?

Comment: Probably because the file is larger than (2^32 - 1) bytes.

Comment: yes the file size is about 8GB. i tried with is_dir and it returns false as expected so i'll use this function

Comment: maybe the problem is that your **php process** is not allowed to READ the file? check the file permissions and check the documentation of is_file. there are also differences in PHP file_size when using in 32 or 64 bit environment.

Comment: but i'm on windows so are there file permissions too ?